# mod bucketing (partitioning, segmenting)

Tags: hash, modulo

I want to partition a list of numbers into `n` buckets. I have seen this trick a lot:

`bucket_index(x) = x mod n_buckets`

I however can't find an authoritative source which describes this trick. Does it have a name? I would like to know the characteristics and limitations of the technique. Does anyone have references they could point me to?

Answer (score 0):

This is basically a Hash Table, where the bucket ID is the hash value of the element. You can read more about hash functions: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function

In your case `bucket_index(x) = x mod n_buckets` is a hash function that maps element `x` to some `bucket_index`.

The hash function is used to map the search key to an index; the index gives the place in the hash table where the corresponding record should be stored. Hash tables, in turn, are used to implement associative arrays and dynamic sets.

Comment: Whats the limitations of this function? Will it always provide a even distribution of buckets with any input list of numbers?

Comment: You can read more about the hash collisions here: http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~rs/AlgsDS07/10Hashing.pdf. It will not provide an even distribution. It really depends on the function. If you look into your example `n mod n_buckets` and `n_buckets = 3`; the input list is `1, 4, 7, 10, 13, 16` then all the elements will belong to the same bucket, i.e. `1`. However, you can choose different hash function depending on the use-case. Usually, if the elements are uniformly distributed then the buckets will have even distributions.